# Instability (quasi-randomness?) of results given by NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I am running on `Mathematica 11.3` an unfortunately long `NDSolve` for Pontryagin principle (SIR epidemics), with both initial and end conditions.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
α = 1.2; ρ = 1.01;
γ  = 1/18; R0 = 2.88;  β  = γ  R0; 
h = ((# - 1 - Log[#])/#) &; di = Log[R0 Exp[1]];
bl = 1.1 β/di; Rl = bl/γ; Imc1 = (1 - 1/R0); Imc2 = h[R0];

Print["Rl=", Rl, " iM=", iM = (Imc1 + h[Rl])/2, " s0=", 
 s0 = Exp[R0 (1 - iM) - 1]/R0 + .1, " i0=", i0 = 1 - s0]; 
tf = 80; 
pw = Re[(# /ρ)^(1/(-1 + ρ))] &;

arg = Min[β, Max[β - pw[#], bl]] &(*doesn't work with Piecewise*); 

upon[t_] := arg[i[t]  s[t] (pi[t] - ps[t] )];
sol = NDSolve[{
        s'[t] == - u[t]*s[t]* i[t], 
        i'[t] == i[t] ( u[t]*s[t] - γ ), 
        ps'[t] == u[t] i[t] (ps[t] - pi[t]), 
        pi'[t] == u[t] i[t] (ps[t] - pi[t]) - α + pi[t] γ, 
        i[0] == i0, s[0] == s0, ps[tf] == 0, 
        pi[tf] == (α/γ )} /. u[t] -> upon[t], 
      {i, s, ps, pi}, {t, 0, tf}, Method -> {"Shooting"}];

ψ[t] := (pi[t] - ps[t])*s[t]*i[t] /. sol;
uop = Plot[
        {Evaluate[(upon[t]/β) /. sol], 
         Evaluate[i[t]/i0 /. sol], 
         Evaluate[ψ[t] /. sol]},
        {t, 0, tf}, 
        PlotLegends -> {"b[t]/β", "i[t]/i0", "ψ[t]"}, 
        Epilog -> {Black, Dashed, Line[{{0, 1}, {tf, 1}}]}, 
        PlotLabel -> Style[Framed["Plot of b/β for ρ=1.01 et α=1.2"], 16, Blue, Background -> Lighter[Yellow]], 
        AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

The result looks almost plausible. Then, I changed (copy-paste) the time from `tf = 80` to `tf = 81`, drastic change, then to `tf = 80.5` drastic change, and then back to `tf = 80`, after which the outputs stabilized, but very different from the first experiment with  `tf = 80`.  I cleared the kernel, but still I could not reproduce the first result. It looked a bit like random, converging results. I guess this is a hard question, but could someone advise where  to start looking?

Comment: MMA Version 12.1 Windows 10. Runs smooth with tf=81, Not big change compared with tf=80. If needed I can post a picture.

Comment: I think you are running into machine-precision issues. Turn all your constants to arbitrary-precision numbers (e.g. `alpha = 12/10; rho = 101/100` etc). The calculations are a bit slower at the default WorkingPrecision, but you can either lower the WorkingPrecision, or set an AccuracyGoal or a PrecisionGoal in NDSolve. I see no instability with any of the `tf` values you mentioned. They all give identical results.

Comment: I would also change the argument of `Plot` to `Evaluate[{(upon[t]/β), i[t]/i0, ψ[t]} /. sol]`; no need to evaluate each list term on its own to do the replacement..

Comment: Thanks, the instability with same value of tf seems to have disappeared:) Still, I get different results with 80 and 81, which are not there on 12.1.  Could it be a problem related to `11.3`?